# How to select nodes that belong to the same group in xpath?

Tags: xml, select, xpath, schema

I have an XML document which is valid against an XML schema. The XML schema has group elements (xs:group). These groups are composed of other defined elements. How can I write an XPath expression which will give me all the members of a specified group?

Any ideas?

@Steve:

assume that my xml schema has defined 4 elements (**elem1, elem2, elem3, elem4**). in addition, 2 groups are defined as follows:

```
group1: (elem1 | elem2 | elem3)
group2: (elem1 | elem4)
```

I hope you know some regular expressions. if no, then 'group2: (elem1 | elem4)' simply means group2 consists of EITHER an elem1 OR an elem4.

My question is if I have an xml document like:

```
<elem1/>
<elem2/>
<elem3/>
<elem4/>
<elem2/>
<elem1/>
<elem3/>
```

How can I list the elements in that document which belong to, say, group1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="elem0"/>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:group ref="A1"/>
                    <xs:group ref="A2"/>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="elem0" type="xs:string"/>

    <xs:group name="A1">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element ref="elem10"/>
            <xs:element ref="elem11"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>

    <xs:element name="elem10" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="elem11" type="xs:string"/>

    <xs:group name="A2">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element ref="elem20"/>
            <xs:element ref="elem21"/>
            <xs:element ref="elem22"/>
            <xs:element ref="elem23"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>

    <xs:group name="CE">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element ref="elem30"/>
            <xs:element ref="elem31"/>
            <xs:element ref="elem32"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>

    <xs:group name="E">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element ref="elem30"/>
            <xs:element ref="elem40"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>

    <xs:element name="elem20">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:group minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="CE"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="elem21">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:group minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2" ref="CE"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="elem22">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="elem40"/>
                <xs:group ref="CE"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="elem23">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="elem40"/>
                <xs:element ref="elem40"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <!-- <xs:attribute name="prop" use="required" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/> -->
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="elem31">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:group minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="CE"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="elem32">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:group ref="CE"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <!-- <xs:attribute name="prop" use="required"/> -->
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="elem30">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="name" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="elem40">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="name" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: If you give some sample XML, and an example of what you'd like to select, I can help you with the XPath expression.

Comment: xml files i'm dealing with are big so i'll quickly try to come up witb a simple one

Comment: @temelm I deleted and migrated some of the questions you asked to be deleted. However, I left some of them alone because they have good answers. Deleting them would be unfair to those who took their time to answer your questions. If you still don't want them linked to you, you can contact the team at `team@stackoverflow.com` and ask them to dissociate them from your account. Unfortunately, we moderators can't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK... there are a few things I think we need to clarify in your example - because, while they may seem like small points, in reality they aren't - and, if you're following the rules, it should be straight-forward how to construct the XPath expression (I'll show examples of how to construct basic XPath expressions taking groups into account for valid schemas, then what the problem I have with your example is).

Let's take it in steps.

### Groups with Sequences

First, let's assume that you have a schema which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:group ref="group1"/>
                <xs:group ref="group2"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:group name="group1">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="elem1"/>
            <xs:element name="elem2"/>
            <xs:element name="elem3"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>
    <xs:group name="group2">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="elem1"/>
            <xs:element name="elem2"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>
</xs:schema>
```

In this case, the important thing to notice is that we have a **sequence** of `group1` followed by `group2` both of which are **sequences** of elements.

With a **sequence**, (and no `minoccurs='0'` attribute on any of the `group` elements - which would be invalid anyways as I'll explain later), selecting the required elements is trivial.

To select all elements of `group1` we might simply use the following XPath:

`/root/(elem1[1]|elem2[1]|elem3)`

This works because we know the resulting XML will **always** be:

```
<root>
     <elem1 />
     <elem2 />
     <elem3 />
     <elem1 />
     <elem2 />
</root>
```

So, that's fine. We can select always the first `elem1`, first `elem2` and the `elem3`.

### Groups with Choices

Lets assume that instead of those groups containing sequences, that instead they contained **choices**. With the schema looking like this:

*(This is more along the lines of the schema you put in your example, where "group2 consists of EITHER an elem1 OR an elem4.")*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:group ref="group1"/>
                <xs:group ref="group2"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:group name="group1">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="elem1"/>
            <xs:element name="elem2"/>
            <xs:element name="elem3"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>
    <xs:group name="group2">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="elem1"/>
            <xs:element name="elem2"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>
</xs:schema>
```

In this case, the XPath is still trivial to construct, because we know there will only be two elements, and the first will belong to `group1` and the second will belong to `group2`, like so:

```
<root>
     <elem2 />
     <elem1 />
</root>
```

So the `group1` XPath is even simpler:

`/root/*[1]`

### Unique Particle Attribution

Here is where it might get confusing - and where, I believe, the source of your confusion comes in.

In your example, you basically have suggested the following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:group ref="group1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:group ref="group2" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:group name="group1">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="elem1"/>
            <xs:element name="elem2"/>
            <xs:element name="elem3"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>
    <xs:group name="group2">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="elem1"/>
            <xs:element name="elem2"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>
</xs:schema>
```

**This schema is invalid.** (Notice the addition of the `maxOccurs="unbounded"` attribute on the groups). This is similar to your example where you show multiple elements from one group occurring).

Why? Well, because it creates a potential ambiguity in the resulting XML.

For example, how should we parse the following XML instance:

```
<root>
     <elem2 />
     <elem1 />
     <elem1 />
     <elem2 />
</root>
```

Is that:

- `group1`, `group1`, `group1`, `group1`
- or `group1`, `group1`, `group1`, `group2`
- or `group1`, `group1`, `group2`, `group1`
- or `group1`, `group2`, `group1`, `group1`
- ...

We just don't know.

But the designers of XML Schemas thought about that and made a rule for it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_Particle_Attribution

And your hypothetical schema violates that rule.

Now, v1.1 does make some improvements in this area... however, there are still situations where you can easily create similar ambiguities.

In your example, if no elements 3 or 4 are present in the xml, it's really quite impossible to tell where group1 ends and group2 begins.

Now, if all you want to do is select elements with a particular name, you can do that easily:

`/root/(elementName1|elementName2|elementName3)`

would select all elements under `root` with the names `elementName1` or `elementName2` or `elementName3`.

So, in your example, something like: `(elem1|elem2|elem3)` would be just fine.

But, that's not what you asked. What you asked was about selecting by group - and the example you provided made it impossible to give you a real answer for *by group*.

If you have a *real*, *valid* schema, and you need help constructing the XPath, please paste *that* schema, and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Wow, long answer. +1 for effort.

Comment: thank you for your detailed explanation. i think my problem is a little bit more tricky and guess i'm still a bit confused. i've edited the question and included my scheme. my question is: how can i get all the members of group A2? thanks

Comment: There will only be one "member" of group A2 at any time. And, it will be the 5th element in the XML. XPath: `/*[5]`

Comment: i am guessing selecting A2 can be as easy as (/root/elem20 | /root/elem21 | /root/elem22 | /root/elem23) am i right? but how about selecting all CE members? i mean CE and C share elem30

Comment: No. The CE element will always be the 6th element. There is no other way. `/*[6]` is CE.

Comment: i dont understand how we can just say /*[5] and go to the 5th element. wouldn't that just select 1 element and maybe its children? i want all elements that belong to my specified group

Comment: Because, based on the schema you posted, A2 is **always** the 5th element - and only the 5th element - there is no other possibility.